# How to define class method with partially applied function?

Tags: scala

I want to define a class's method with a partially applied method. Is that possible to do without fully applying the method?

This is my best shot:

```
def getFile1(arg1: String) (implicit execution: ExecutionContextExecutor): Future[File] =
  getFile("file 1")_

def getFile2(arg1: String) (implicit execution: ExecutionContextExecutor): Future[File] =
  getFile("file 2")_

def getFile(fileName: String)(arg1: String)(implicit execution: ExecutionContextExecutor): Future[File] = //...
```

What happens though is that instead of making `getFile1(arg1)` and `getFile('file 1', arg1)` equivalent, the Scala tries to evaluate `getFile("File 2")_` and sees an error because the type of `getFile("File 2")_` is a function, not a file.

Answer (score 3):

The error is correct. The `getFile("..")_` is an *expression* inside the method (that evaluates to a partial function) and it is *not* 'a method definition'.

Writing it out as the following should make this more clear:

```
def getFile2(arg1: String) (implicit execution: ExecutionContextExecutor): Future[File] = {
  return getFile("file 2")_
}
```

Contrast with `getFile("file 2")(arg1)`, which has the expected expression type/result of Future[File].

If wanting the method to *return* a partially applied function then change the return type from Future[File] to whatever is appropriate. (Or let the type inference do what it's gonna do.)

Comment: I know that's what's happening. What I'm asking is whether there is a way to get around that.

Comment: Yes (or no, depending on view): return the correct type per the *actual* signature or change the signature. There is no such 'meta alias' feature. Even if creating a `val` (in which case the implicit would not work) it would still need to be *correctly typed* per the partial method.